# MyRuntime.exec() saying file not found

Tags: java, runtime.exec, external-process

This is JAVA programming language question

This is the code im trying to execute :

```
MyRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
File temp = new File("C:\\Command Line Apps\\cURL\\");
for(String filenames : temp.list()) System.out.println(filenames);
curl = MyRuntime.exec("curl.exe", null, temp);
```

The output is :

```
java ScreenshotMaker

build.txt
CHANGES
COPYING
curl.exe
curl.html
curl.pdf
libcurl.dll
libeay32.dll
libidn-11.dll
libssl32.dll
mk-ca-bundle.vbs
README
RELEASE-NOTES
_curlrc
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl" (in di
rectory "C:\Command Line Apps\cURL"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot f
ind the file specified
```

As you can see, the curl.exe is present in the directory.
but
Runtime.exec() doesn't seem to recognize it..

What do i do to fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: Try giving the full path to `curl.exe`. The working directory may not have an effect on the search path.

Comment: And maybe there is a Java library you can use instead of curl.

Answer (score 0):

try to use folder name without spaces such as use  CommandLineApps instead of "Command Line Apps"